# Configure hostname as user

Tags: hostname, user

In Linux I would like to give a hostname to an IP address so that I can do

```
vncviewer hostname
```

Is this possible without root permission?

I am looking for something like `HostName` in `.ssh/config` but not limited to `ssh`.

Comment: Editing `/etc/hosts` does require root, an alternative solution is to ask your sys admin to add entry on dns srv

Answer (score 1):

No. a root permission is needed to change hostname!